# How to print escaped HTML entities as is in Python (xml.etree.ElementTree)?

Tags: python

[This Python script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577547-flatten-xml-to-xpath-syntax-lines/) flattens XML to a list of xpath=value pairs.

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<P>
  <Q HTML="&lt;head&gt;&#13;&#10;    &lt;style ...">text</Q>
</P>
```

The output is

```
//P
//P/Q=text
//P/Q/@HTML=<head>
    <style ...
```

which unescapes the HTML entities `&lt; &#13; ...`.  How to make it print values exactly as in XML, like `//P/Q/@HTML=&lt;head&gt;&#13;&#10;    &lt;style ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1. from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

...

27. print path + "[line %d]=%s " % (lineNb, escape(line))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I put escape to all occurrences of print.  The result is `//P/Q/@HTML=&lt;head&gt;  NEWLINE
    &lt;style ...
`.   So `&#13;&#10;` is still converted.

Comment: So you want to preserve white space? Maybe try this instead: http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm

Comment: I need to preserve newlines `&#13;&#10;`, so that each line of the output is a xpath=value pair.  Preserving white spaces or not does not matter.

Comment: Try this Line 35: print path + "/@" + removeNS(name) + "=" + escape(val).replace('\r', '&#13;').replace('\n', '&#10')

Comment: Should be `&#10;` but yes that is good.  Just want to ask, I see characters are unescaped and then escaped again.  Is there no way to keep no unescaping in the first place?

Comment: You might consider creating a custom sax parser: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html#module-xml.sax.handler But I'm not sure how much work it would be.